# What is this type of fixing? (similar to cam/dowel)

Tags: screws, fastener, joinery, fastening

I know this is similar to cam or dowel type fixings, and I have searched extensively for this part, but does anyone know exactly what type this is? Specifically the silver section, as I have enough of the screws/tighteners left, but I need more of the fixings.

[image: cam or dowel type fixings]

They are not quite the same as generic cam/dowel fixings as they have this cut out for the screw to go in and hold them in place.

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: What is this too? Furniture? Contact the manufacturer of the item and ask for more or replacements. That is a dowel but it looks like rather than a cam twist, you have a set screw. I have now come across this type yet. Is this perhaps a new Ikea thing? Try a small hardware store like Ace or True Value that might have odds and ends of these things. I have left overs from broken furniture, but they are the twist cam type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more reasearch, it appears to be flat pack furniture assembly cam and dowel, more common on newer Ikea furniture. Try calling Ikea or checking online with them about replacement parts or extra parts. Or perhaps contact the manufacturer of the connector.

https://www.engineering.com/AdvancedManufacturing/ArticleID/11459/Better-Connectors-The-Future-of-Flatpack-Furniture.aspx

https://www.glaserbolt.com/torpedo/products